# Calculate Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) by reading a .txt file in matlab

Tags: matlab, svd

I want to calculate Singular value decomposition (SVD) by reading a text file. In my .txt file include an integer data like,

```
1 5 6 7
3 2 4 1
7 5 9 4
6 3 1 5
```

I could do it manually including data like the following code. (Here I extend it to calculate LSA too) But how to do the same calculation by reading the file?

```
A = [1 5 6 7;3 2 4 1; 7 5 9 4; 6 3 1 5]
[U, S, V] = svd(A)
VP = V.'
AR = U * S * VP

U2 = U(:,1:2)
S2 = S(1:2,1:2)
VP2 = VP(:,1:2)
V2 = VP2.'

A2 = U2 * S2 * V2
```

Comment: Quite a few options for loading a text file in the answers of the linked duplicate.

Comment: I could do it using `data = load('c:\\input.txt', '-ascii');`.Thank you for your suggestion. Actually, I have a large dataset `9970X1000` size matrix. So Can I use the same way for load a large dataset?

Comment: That should work, assuming you have the memory available to store the matrix variable.